# Failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys

Tags: rust, substrate

Does anybody know what should I install to fulfill `librocksdb-sys` dependency? I was trying to solve it with `apt install clang` but does not solve the issue. My best guess is that it is some error connected with linking and/or versioning.

Appreciate any hints.

> error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v0.8.0+7.4.4`
>
> Caused by:   process didn't exit successfully:
> `/home/tomek/ssd/workspaces/substrate/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-dcab8f317e6498cb/build-script-build`
> (exit status: 101)   --- stderr   thread 'main' panicked at
> '"enum_(unnamed_at_rocksdb/include/rocksdb/c_h_981_1)" is not a valid
> Ident',
> /home/tomek/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/proc-macro2-1.0.46/src/fallback.rs:756:9
> note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a
> backtrace warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

The error occurs on Debian.

Comment: It's probably one of `[lib]rocksdb[-dev]` depending on your distribution.

Comment: It is true, there is the dependency of `rocksdb`, any idea how to fulfill the dependency on my operating system?

Comment: I relly don't have one as I don't even know what your OS is. But as I said the package is probably called one of `[lib]rocksdb[-dev]` where `[]` denote an optional part. You'll then have to use your package manager to install said package.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error on M1 and was able to solve it by downgrading to clang 14 as suggested by @kevindong on GitHub

```bash
brew install llvm@14
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm@14/bin:$PATH" 
clang --version # Should return 14
#... Your command here
```

See: https://github.com/rust-rocksdb/rust-rocksdb/issues/768#issuecomment-1767143727

Related Substrate question: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6088/unable-to-compile-substrate-template-error-failed-to-run-custom-build-command